# Sass is reorganizing my selectors and it's breaking functionality

Tags: css, sass

Here's the compiled code:

```
/* line 5, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.tile::after, .tile::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* line 16, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.tile {
  width: 40px;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 40px;
  height: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

/* line 23, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.tile::after {
  width: 40px;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 40px;
  height: 2.5rem;
  top: 4px;
  top: 0.25rem;
}

/* line 30, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.tile::before {
  width: 48px;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 44px;
  height: 2.75rem;
  top: 4px;
  top: 0.25rem;
  left: -4px;
  left: -0.25rem;
}

/* line 40, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.large {
  width: 248px;
  width: 15.5rem;
  height: 248px;
  height: 15.5rem;
}

/* line 46, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.large::after {
  width: 248px;
  width: 15.5rem;
  height: 248px;
  height: 15.5rem;
}

/* line 51, ../scss/_layout.scss */
.large::before {
  width: 256px;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 252px;
  height: 15.75rem;
}

/* line 5, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background: gray;
}

/* line 11, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile::after {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background: red;
}

/* line 17, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile::before {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: black;
}

/* line 23, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile:hover {
  background: cyan;
}

/* line 26, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile:hover::after {
  background: orange;
}

/* line 29, ../scss/_style.scss */
.tile:hover::before {
  background: blue;
}
```

The scss:

```
// Layout


// Pseudo
%pseudo{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

// Default
$width: 48;
$height: 48;

.tile{
    @include size($width - 8, $height - 8);
    @include rem-box(margin, 8, x, x, 4);
    position: relative;
}

// Depth
.tile::after{
    @extend %pseudo;
    @include size($width - 8 , $height - 8);
    @include position(4, x, x, x);
}

// Border
.tile::before{
    @extend %pseudo;
    @include size($width, $height - 4);
    @include position(4, x, x, -4);
}

// Large
$width: 256;
$height: 256;

.large{
    @include size($width - 8, $height - 8);
    //@include rem-box(margin, x, x, x, 4);
}

// Depth
.large::after{
    @include size($width - 8 , $height - 8);
}

// Border
.large::before{
    @include size($width, $height - 4);
}
```

It starts with "tile" then goes to "large" then back to "tile." Is there a way to prevent it from compiling this way? I've tried nesting it differently, but nothing. I don't *want* to create 2 completely different divs, but I guess I'll have to if I can't solve this problem. I plan on making this a lot more complex. I just want to modify an existing div by adding classes.

Comment: Wouldn't this be in compile settings? what are you using to compile?

Comment: Where's the Sass?  Looking at the compiled CSS isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: @cimmanon The sass is simple. It's almost identical to the compiled version, just re-arranged.

Comment: @derek_duncan I'm using Scout to compile. There's no settings like that in Scout that I'm aware of.

Comment: Make sure you are providing enough code that it will actually compile.  The more work we have to do, the longer it takes to get your answer.  As it stands, there's not enough Sass to reproduce the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like it is reordering anything. According to the compiled CSS, your problem is that you have actually two different styles for the selector `.tile` in two different files — one in _layout.scss and one in _style.scss. The definitions from _layout.scss (which include the first `.tile` as well as the `.large` styles) are placed first, and then the definitions from _style.scss (which include the second set of `.tile` styles) come after.

Comment: Oooooh. Duh. Thank you for pointing that out. If I define them in _layout.scss first and just modify them _style.scss they should order how I want.